# how to prevent xss in server side in a java spring mvc application?

Tags: java, xss, fortify

I need to handle the XSS in the server-side of my java spring application.

I have tried using the `XSSRequestWrapper` which will extend the `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. By using this I am able to prevent the XSS for the header and request parameter. But not able to handle the request body. Please suggest how to handle the XSS for the Request body.

Comment: Please refer: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: XSS should be prevented by encoding output data correctly. I wouldn't rely on anything based on processing request data. If it's anything like [https://dzone.com/articles/stronger-anti-cross-site](https://dzone.com/articles/stronger-anti-cross-site) then it's easily bypassed.